# How to decide if a user has 'read notification' in asp.net identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, algorithm, asp.net-identity

I am having a little bit of trouble with an algorithm, or best way to go about achieving a certain 'notification' functionality within my website.

Currently, I am using asp.net identity to allow users to register on my site (not much new here, i know).

but as for a functionality point of view, I thought adding a notification section would be quite useful. However, I am slightly confused as to how to ensure 'this user has seen this' before deleting it from the database...

I have a table like:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| NotificationID  | Notification   | remove      |
| <int, auto      | <text>         | <bit>       |
|  increment>     |                |             |
+------------------------------------------------+
|                 |                |             |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

And I'm using ajax to add this into my `_layout.cshtml` page..

My rendered html looks something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.navbar').click(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("openNav");
            });
            
            updateSideBar();
            $(document).on('click', '.rightSidebar .close', function (e) {
                var val = parseInt($('.rightSidebar .tog').attr("data-cont"));
                val = val - 1;
                $('.rightSidebar .tog').attr("data-cont", val);
                $(this).parent().remove();

                var countthi = $('.rightSidebar .right-content').size();
                $('.rightSidebar .tog').attr("data-cont", countthi);
                if(countthi < 1)
                {
                    $('.rightSidebar .tog').attr("data-cont", "");
                    $('.rightSidebar').removeClass("sidebaractive");
                }
            });

            function updateSideBar() {
                var countthi = $('.rightSidebar .right-content').size();
                $('.rightSidebar .tog').attr("data-cont", countthi);
            }
            $('.rightSidebar .tog').click(function () {
                $('.rightSidebar').toggleClass("sidebaractive");
            });
        });
```

```css
.rightSidebar {
     position:absolute;
     top:100px;
     right:-190px;
     background:rgba(34,34,34,1);
     transition:all 0.6s;
     width:200px;
     z-index:10;
     height:0px;     
     border:5px double cornflowerblue;
     border-right:none;
 }
 .right-content {
     width:90%;
     padding-bottom:10px;
     padding-top:10px;
     margin-left:-webkit-calc(10% - 5px);
     margin-left:calc(10% - 5px);
     position:relative;
     margin-top:10px;
    transition:all 0.6s;
     border-left:5px double rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
 }
.right-content:hover{
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1)
}
 .close {
     display:inline-block;
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     right:0;
     height:20px;
     width:20px;
     cursor:pointer;
     border-radius:50%;
     z-index:10;
 }
 .close:before, .close:after {
     content:"";
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     left:-webkit-calc(50% - 2px);
     left:calc(50% - 2px);
     width:4px;
     height:100%;
     cursor:pointer;
     background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 }
 .close:before {
     -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
     transform:rotate(45deg);
 }
 .close:after {
     -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
     transform:rotate(-45deg);
 }

 .sidebaractive {
     right:0px;
     height:50vh;    
 }
 .tog{
     position:absolute;
     top:-30px;
     left:-30px;
     height:40px;
     width:40px;
     border-radius:50%;
     transition:all 0.6s;
     background:rgba(34,34,34,1);
     border:5px double rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
     overflow:hidden;
     color:gold;
 }
 .tog:hover:before{
     background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
 }
 .tog:before{
     content:attr(data-cont);
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
     height:40px;
     width:40px;
     position:absolute;
     text-align:center;
     line-height:40px;
 }
 .sidebaractive .tog{
     border:5px double lightgray;
 }
  .sidebaractive:before{
content:"";
     position:absolute;
     bottom:-30px;
     left:-30px;
     height:40px;
     width:40px;
     border-radius:50%;
     transition:all 0.6s;
     background:rgba(34,34,34,1);
     border:5px double cornflowerblue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rightSidebar" data-cont="">
        <div class="tog"></div>
        
            <div id="divResult"></div>
        
    </div>
```

---

Rendered markup:
[image]

---

My issue, however, is that I'm displaying all the 'notifications' within the table, and subsequently when i delete from my view, it deletes from everyone elses..

My question is: How would i design this so that I know 'user A' has deleted this, as has 'user B' (so it doesn't appear anymore from them).

However, user C doesn't log on for a while, so I don't want them to miss seeing it.

So in this case, user A and B have dismissed it/removed from their view, but when user C logs in, they can still see it until they too delete it?

Is there a way of iterating and selecting users who haven't yet deleted it?

I was thinking of including an 'array of everyone who *hasn't* seen it', and saving it in the db in a separate column. Once they 'delete it', remove them from the list. But this seems ***very*** inefficient, especially as the site grows with users.

Would anyone have a suggestion as to how this could be achieved?

Comment: Are you really that short of database space? Is it a problem to keep a notifications stack for each user, with info such as date added, date viewed?

Comment: @TAMTAM: It's not being short of database space, it's more to do with *efficiency* of this design. This sort of 'list' would be quite slow to read, iterate, remove, and update each time - let alone about collisions!

Comment: Well another design would be to keep a "last notification read date" field on each user and compare this with the notifications date to send only the new ones. You could then periodically check for and delete the notifications read by all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented something similar in my application, and the design serving the purpose.

I got following DB table that store a mapping between user and notification with a flag whether that user has acknowledged it or not. NotificationId comes from NotificationMessage table that store notification details like messageText, startDate, endDate.

I query this table to check notification pending for logged in user based on userId and show them notification where IsAcknowledged = false.

[image]

I am hoping this will help you.

Comment: This would be possible... how'd you decide if the notification was 'read by all'?

Comment: Do you really want to know that? It wasn't a requirement when I designed this solution so there could be a better design but if its a new requirement now I will just check acknowledged notification count == user count.

Comment: I've implemented this approach, ty for your fresh idea :)